# How do I test voltage without a ground/confirm a good circuit?

Tags: electrical, voltage, diy-vs-pro, multimeter

For context, I recently moved (into a very old home) and I have a series of recessed lights operating on a single switch. All but one light fine... what I assume is the last in the series does not. There is only a black and red wire present -- no ground, and no neutral as far as I can tell. When I test with a non-contact voltage tester, both the black and red wires are hot when the switch is on, and no voltage on either is present when it is off.

I have not tested with a voltage meter yet as there is no ground or neutral wire present so wasn't sure the correct/safe way to do that. How can I determine the voltage of each wire, and if this is appropriate to properly complete a circuit to get a working light in this space?

[image]

Comment: Open up one of the other light fixtures and see what wires are there. That way we know the "normal" and it may shed some light (pun intended) on this one.

Comment: I have. It's the same setup... only a black and red wire, with a MR16 pigtail/can attached to either side, and a 5V MR16 LED bulb into it. In the case of this one, attaching the pigtail did not product a working light, despite the line(s) clearly being powered.

Comment: 5V????? Do you mean 5W?

Comment: Ugh. Typo. Yes :)

Comment: Something strange going on. Sounds like either some wires are the wrong color or the lights are wired in series. But if they were wired in series then any one light out would stop them all from working.

Comment: Wires colors show  is DC. Red plus, black minus. The last bulb may not have enough power because of drop voltage on wires.

Comment: @user263983 Interesting! I had not considered that before but it might make the most sense. Is there some way I can account for that?

Comment: Multimeter may show.  And you may look out for DC power supply. Also read the voltage on another bulbs, powered by this circuit.

Comment: Thanks... will test!

Comment: Yes, you should not be wiring 120V bulbs to these wires. Neutral being white is not optional.  Also the lack of a junction box suggests either horrible work, or low voltage DC, where red/black are normal colors.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I am not wiring 120V, rather 5W MR16 bulbs. Once user263983 suggested DC, it all made sense. There is a block of DC transformers located under the stairs. As I said, we recently moved here and it has been a journey of discovery :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm in PA, USA :)

Comment: @acraigl can you post a photo looking into the back of the box/hole then please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There is no box, and the hole is less than 3 inches in diameter. I can't even get my phone up in there. I do have an endoscope though and didn't see anything notable save for some plumbing and duct work, and of course the wires shown here.